# Diferença entre scheduleAtFixedRate e schedule na classe ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, android, timer, scheduler

Qual é a diferença entre `scheduleAtFixedRate` e `schedule`?

Eu estou a desenvolver uma app em Android que quero que tenha um atraso de 50 minutos antes de iniciar uma acção e que repita essa mesma acção nos próximos 50 minutos, mas gostaria de saber qual delas irá satisfazer a minha necessidade, neste caso.

Comment: Creio que `AtFixedRate` seja para repetições, pois implica em uma frequência (scheduleAtFixedRate = agendarA_TaxaFixa). O "_" foi para respeitar o camelCase :D

Comment: Okay ... Grato :)

Comment: Se solucionou a pergunta, me avise que eu converto o comentário em resposta.

Answer (score 2):

A diferença entre este métodos é a seguinte:

**ScheduledExecutorService.schedule**

Ao chamar esse método você deve definir um `Runnable` que é sua task, o time que a ação deverá ser executada e o TimeUnit(se e hoars, minutos, etc). Este método executará o que nós chamamos de *one-shot action*. Seu runnable será executado apenas uma vez no tempo definido.(existem versões overloaded que aceitam Calleables ao invés de Runnables)

**ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtAFixedRate**

Já na chamada do `scheduleAtAFixedRate` o m[etodo Cria e executa uma ação - `Runnable/Callable` periódica que é ativada pela primeira vez após o atraso inicial dado. Se qualquer execução da tarefa de lançar uma exceção, execuções subseqüentes são suprimidos, ou seja não são executadas. Caso contrário, a tarefa só vai terminar via cancelamento ou shutidown do `executor`.

**Atente-se a este detalhe:**

Se qualquer execução desta tarefa levar mais tempo do que o seu período, então as execuções subsequentes podem serão startadas mais tarde, mas não haverá execução **simultania**.

Por favor de uma olhada nos JavaDocs

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html